# hack attack or mvc bugs available on my controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

recently i published my new website, i developed it on mvc5 and i put a piece of code on a global.aspx to log errors if happened.

after a while i saw some users are try to hack my website ,because on my log file i have got some logs like this:

```
IP: 94.xxx.xxx.xxx General Error:
The controller for path '/admin/index.php' 
was not found or does not implement IController.
```

it seems someone did try to find some information.

but why i have got this errors:

```
IP: 4x.xxx.xxx.xxx General Error:
 A public action method 'Center﻿' was not found on controller 
'XXX.Controllers.SMSController'.
```

my controller has this action and i tested it , it works fine.

is this a hack trying or something like this or is a bug on mvc?

my codes:

```
 protected void Application_Error()
    {
                var exception = Server.GetLastError();
                var httpException = exception as HttpException;
                Response.Clear();
                Server.ClearError();

                xxx.Loger.PointLoger.LogIt("\r\n"+
                "On IP: " +HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress 
                +" General Error:\r\n" + httpException.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Appears someone is attempting routes that don't exist. They've attempted /admin/index.php which isn't very compatible with your ASP.NET MVC application (not PHP). The other it appears they're going for /SMS/Center. Is this supposed to be a valid route? If so, the method may need to be switched to public. Otherwise, they may be looking for endpoints. Purely speculating though.

Comment: thanks for your time and yes /SMS/Center is a valid rout and works fine

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with MVC5, but the internet is full of bots that are trying every single address and website for common folders, for example

```
/pma
/phpmyadmin
/admin
...
```